# @ operator not defined

Tags: c++, operators

I am reading through a `.cpp` trying to figure out some things and came across code like this:

```
some_function()
{
    CustomClass some_sort_of_list;
    string sample;
    if (sample != "") {
        some_sort_of_list = @BOING(args);
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen the `@` operator before, or is it just `#define` used somewhere in one of the header files? I do not have access to the headers.

Since @Captain Obvlious mentioned early versions of Visual C++, I will look there to see what is going on...

PS: I should mention also, in case it's not obvious enough, that the names have been changed since I don't know if I have the license to share this source. The main issue is the `@SOMETHING`.

PPS: the comments are in Japanese, and I have limited access to the original authors.

Comment: Are you sure it's C++ and not C#?

Comment: IIRC older versions of VC++ allow `@` in identifiers.

Comment: It looks like a token used for generating code. In other words, the code generator will replace the `@GEN` with something else.

Comment: @Јοеу - it's in a .cpp, so C++ is my default guess. I know file extensions don't mean much, but conventions are there for a reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not standard C++, it's not even legal as a `#define` since they're not permitted to start with `@`.

It's probably something that gets run through a pre-processor of some sort, like Oracle's Pro*C compiler which can turn `EXEC SQL` into C function calls, before passing to an *actual* C compiler.

Your best bet would be to think about the *environment* that this code runs in, such as "is it an internationalised application where `@GEN` may retrieve a locale-specific string for output?".

And, since, you mention that the comments are in Japanese, you should at least give [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) a try. It can sometimes result in hilarity for complex phrases but it may well give you a needed clue.

Comment: Thanks. Someone on IRC suggested it could have to do with `autotools`, which I am not yet familiar with.

Comment: @icedwater, I've never seen the `@xx()` syntax in automake and its brethren.

Comment: I am, of course. It's useful since Japanese is one of the languages I would like to learn too. I hope you have grilled your problem though.

Also, yes, it is part of an application that offers three languages at least - how would i18n be relevant here though? *searches*

Comment: @icedwater, it's only useful as an _example_ of what the `@whatever` snippet may do. It might return a translated list, it may return a sorted list, it may do any number of things. What I was stating is that other information than you've provided in the question may help to ascertain what it's meant to do.

Comment: yes @paxdiablo, I know it was just a suggestion. Say, for example, it returns a translated list. What I wanted to know was where would such a construct (e.g. that `@FUNC` maps to the correct language version of `FUNC`) be defined?

Comment: @icedwater, it could be _anywhere!_ It's not standard C++ and, based on the fact there are precious few answers, it's not well known. Which means you'll need to do some investigation of the environment, how things are compiled, what tools are available and so on. All I can give are some possibilities which, though educated, _may_ be totally off-base. That's probably the best anyone can do given the limited information, short of someone showing up here that knows exactly the tools you're using.

Comment: Aww you removed the sentence.